# custom textbox with formula property

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I created a custom textbox and add a formula property to it. I want to type a formula like textbox1+textbox2+textbox3 in the property that textbox1,2,3 are regular textboxes in the main form. it's my challenge is how to change value of custom textbox whenever the textboxes values changed? I don't want to use text_change method of each three textbox.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you are going to do this without using a text changed method.  Or why you want to avoid doing that.  Unless you just mean you don't want to write the same method for each of the 3 textBoxes.

What I would do is write a method, call it updateCustomTextbox or whatever and in it assign that textBox the concatenated string of textBoxes 1, 2, and 3.  Then I would just call this method from each of the textChanged events for all of those 3 textBoxes.

Editing to add code to show what I mean.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _3ConcatenatedTextBoxes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            changeTextBox4();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            changeTextBox4();
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            changeTextBox4();
        }

        private void changeTextBox4()
        {
            textBox4.Text = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text;
        }
    }
}
```